how to setup react native for physical android device
I'm trying to properly setup react native app in physical android device and I am able to run the app but not able make network request like login or fetch data from server and constantly getting " ERROR  [TypeError: Network request failed]" .  And I'm using native cli (not expo).
I did make changes in AndroidManfiest.xml file to recognize internet, clear traffic for http requests, use local IP address but nothing seems to be working here. Expecting some resource , reference regrading how to properly setup react native cli (not expo) with physical device including network request.

Is the backend in local or the cloud server?

would you mind sharing some code or error logs so that we can figure out what might be the issue

make sure your API have SSL certificate

Update the AndroidManifest.xml file.
add this android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag.This look like and after added re-run application
<application
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


Apps with that turned on aren't allowed in the Play Store without very good reason. because they have no security.  And while this might be the reason, if they're developing on a local server without an ssl certificate, you really ought to explain what this does and why this would fix it.  Especially as we don't have enough evidence to know this is the problem or not, it's merely an educated guess.

@Ankit Have you tried the solution that Mahil has offered? Has it been successful?

@GabeSechan this solution worked for when we hit http url . If you use https we do not need to add this in AndroidManifest.xml file. And for your information I developed more than 30+ applications and deployed in both platforms so I know which is suitable for security reasons. hope you got it

@Mahii Yes, that flag turns on clear text and allows you to hit an http server.  It's also not allowed in play store apps.  It will be rejected by google if you try to ship with that flag.  You can add it to a debug manifest and be ok, but not to your production one.  And once again, while it MAY be the problem the asker had, we don't have enough information to know that it is.  Especially since he said he did this.
